# Arduino VirtualWire Rf module Send a String

Tags: arduino

Sorry if my post is not well formatted'm new in here.

```
/*
    SimpleSend
    This sketch transmits a short text message using the VirtualWire library
    connect the Transmitter data pin to Arduino pin 12
    */
    #include <VirtualWire.h>

String Mensagem  = "eureca"; //I want to send this string

void setup(){
   // Initialize the IO and ISR
   vw_setup(2000); // Bits per sec
}
void loop(){
    send(Mensagem); //Putting a string inside the function does not work, 
    //I want to send a String message inside that function like a parameter
    delay(1000);
}

void send (char *message){
    vw_send((uint8_t *)message, strlen(message));
    vw_wait_tx(); // Wait until the whole message is gone
}
```

Comment: You begin with the first byte. And when you get to the last byte, stop.

Answer (score 1):

`char *message` means a string literal or a character pointer, but what you're passing into the function is a String. 
You can fix it by using:

```
char Mensagem[]= "eureca";
```

in order to match the type. It's because Mensagem now is a static pointer of that character array.